# Count the occurrences of a group from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

**New** to programming and I am trying to make a script to clean some data from some annotation software. The outputs are in excel.

I have a column with an option of 40 some unique strings. I want to know the single occurrences of each of those potentially 40 strings. (This I have already managed)

```
count = df['Behavior'].value_counts()
print(count)
```

I also want to know the occurrences of groups within those 40 options. Of the 40 they are split into groups 1, 2, 3, and 4 say. How would I make counts of like a list or something within an excel column?

I appreciate any help, and I apologize for my ignorance. Conceptually I know what I want but when fingers hit the keys things go south.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have something like

```
import numpy
import pandas
fourty_strings = ["A","B","C","D"]
groups = ["1","2","3","4"]
num_rows = 100
all_strings = numpy.random.choice(fourty_strings,num_rows)
all_groups = numpy.random.choice(groups,num_rows)

df = pandas.DataFrame({"Behaviour":all_strings,"Group":all_groups})
print(df['Behaviour'].value_counts()) # what you have
```

in which case you can just groupby your Group column, and then aggregate with value_counts

```
print(df.groupby("Group").agg("value_counts")) # what you want i think
```

Comment: I apologize that I was not clear enough. I am reading in a file. Then I am going to a specific column, and I can find the occurrences of each string. For my application those 40 some strings that I have are grouped into a methodology I have. Instead of manually going through value counts output and saying "oh this string is part of group A, add that to the total for group A.". I want to give it a list or a dictionary and say when you are counting the occuerences of strings also give me a total for these specific list of strings. Not sure if that is making sense.

Comment: sorry i guess i dont quite understand what you are asking